# How to parse an xml string in javascript? (not client-side, browser-related)

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I was wondering if anybody could point me to a Core (not client-side) JavaScript solution for parsing an xml string. For example, turning it into an object I could pluck properties out of. Or even an array.

I've searched high and low, and all the solutions I see are client-side solutions which make use of a particular browser's DOM. Please note, I am programming in JavaScript, but this is not a DOM-related question. It's a server-side calculation.

For example, I have this string:
`<IndustryTerm count="2" relevance="0.553">food system</IndustryTerm><Person count="2" relevance="0.586">Alexandra Spieldoch</Person><Event count="1">Environmental Issue</Event><IndustryTerm count="1" relevance="0.154">rural finance</IndustryTerm><IndustryTerm count="1" relevance="0.335">food security</IndustryTerm><IndustryTerm count="1" relevance="0.280">e-consultation</IndustryTerm><IndustryTerm count="1" relevance="0.154">high-level food security dialogues</IndustryTerm><IndustryTerm count="1" relevance="0.154">food markets</IndustryTerm><Position count="1" relevance="0.335">representative</Position><SocialTags><SocialTag importance="2">Sociology<originalValue>Sociology</originalValue></SocialTag><SocialTag importance="2">Food security<originalValue>Food security</originalValue></SocialTag><SocialTag importance="1">Food politics<originalValue>Food politics</originalValue></SocialTag><SocialTag importance="1">Gender<originalValue>Gender</originalValue></SocialTag><SocialTag importance="1">Biology<originalValue>Biology</originalValue></SocialTag></SocialTags>`

My goal is to find all the *relevance* and *importance* values, and the associated values between the tags. To be more specific, in this case:

`<IndustryTerm count="1" relevance="0.154">food markets</IndustryTerm>`

I'd like to know the tag name (IndustryTerm) the relevance (0.154) and the the value between the open and close tags (food markets).

I've been fiddling around with regular expressions, but haven't been able to "hit the spot" yet and was just wondering if there is something out there.

Again, this is not related to client-side JavaScript or browsers, but does need to be in standard, Core JavaScript.

doug

Comment: There are several parsers listed at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-parsers-xml

Answer (score 4):

Core Javascript has built in XML methods, is this what you are looking for?

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X

```
var person = <person>
  <name>Bob Smith</name>
  <likes>
    <os>Linux</os>
    <browser>Firefox</browser>
    <language>JavaScript</language>
    <language>Python</language>
  </likes>
</person>;

alert(person.name); // Bob Smith
alert(person['name']); // Bob Smith
alert(person.likes.browser); // Firefox
alert(person['likes'].browser); // Firefox
```

The link has examples for working with lists, attributes etc.

Comment: I can't believe I never noticed that before. It looks like it was released way back when array and object literals were released in 2005. It looks like it should work with my server-side JS. It does compile, but unfortunately crashes the server when executed. I will talk to the people who created this (unusual) server. It's probably a server bug. I might be the first person using this server to use this feature! But it does look exactly like what I'm looking for. One question: Accessing the properties are clear. But how do you access an attribute? At the link that wasn't clear. Thanks!

Comment: I confirmed that even with the simplest example my server crashes if I try this. Is there an external library of code I can maybe add myself which will do what the missing/buggy code is not doing? Thanks.

Comment: At WikiPedia it says, "Although E4X support is still present, SpiderMonkey no longer allows
E4X syntax when running in ECMAScript 5 "strict mode". We are  sing SpiderMonkey. Is this the problem? Is there an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: w3Schools also says: "E4X is not widely supported. Maybe it offers too little practical functionality not already covered by other solutions." That may be the problem. Perhaps the example shown above isn't a general solution anymore?

Comment: All modern browsers have a built-in XML parser that can convert text into an XML DOM object. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an alternative syntax for parsing XML that is supported by SpiderMonkey. I grabbed a copy of the [SpiderMonkey JavaScript Shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell) from the [Firefox nightly builds page](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/), and stealing from siberian's example, this works:

```
js> options('allow_xml');
""
js> var person = new XML("<person><name>Bob Smith</name><likes><os>Linux</os><browser>Firefox</browser><language>JavaScript</language><language>Python</language></likes></person>");
js> person.name;
<name>Bob Smith</name>
js> person.name.text()
Bob Smith
js> person.likes.browser.text();
Firefox
```